# How do I get the value of a select menu with jquery on change

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I have a select menu that i'm trying to bind a click function and be able to get the select options value attribute back on change.

```
             select = $('#select_networks').selectmenu();

            //bind the change of network/group
            select.bind( "change", function(event, ui) {

              //need to figure out the selected elements value attribute

            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this:

```
$("#select_networks").bind("change", function() {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

**UPDATE**

```
$("#select_networks").bind("change", function() {
    var typeVal = $(this).children("*[value=" + $(this).val() + "]").attr("type");
    alert(typeVal);
});
```

Comment: This got the value fine, but follow up question. How can I pull arbitrary attributes as well. For example I set a type field in the select option, I tried  alert($(this).attr("type")); but I just get undefined.

Answer (score 1):

```
this.value
```

generally you can use it with form elements and it is much faster then wrapping `this` as a jQuery object and then extracting the value.

However in some cases, specifically with select's, you can run into issues in older versions of IE when options with no explicity `value=""`, and jquery takes care of this for you with...

```
$(this).val();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        select.bind( "change", function(event, ui) {

            $(this).children(':selected').val();

        });
```

This will select the selected `<option>`(s).

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4KS9z/1/